# HTTP Response sent before async call returns

Tags: http, asynchronous, request, webserver, response

I am yet to understand the behavior of web server thread, if I make an async call to say, a database, and immediately return response ( say OK ) to the client without even waiting for the async call to return back. First of all, is it a good approach ? What will happen to the thread which made the async call and if it is used again to serve another request and then the previous async call returns to this particular thread. Or does web server holds this thread waiting till the async call which it made, returns. Then the issue would be many hanging threads would be open as and web server would be available to take more requests. I am looking for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the way your HTTP servers works. But you should be very cautious.

Let's say you have a main event loop taking care of incoming HTTP connections, and workers threads which manage the HTTP communications.
A worker thread should be considered ready to accept a new HTTP request management only when it is effectively completly ready for that.

In terms of pure HTTP the more important thing is to **avoid sending a response before having received the whole query**. It seems simple, and it's usually the case. But if the query as a body, which may be a chunked body, it could take time to receive the whole message.
You should **never** send a response before, unless it's something like a 400 bad request response, followed by a real tcp/ip connection closing. If you fail to do so, and you have a message length parsing issue, the fact that you sent a response before the end of the query may lead to security problems. It could be used to exploit differences in the parsing of messages between your server and any other HTTP agent in front of your server (ssl terminator, reverse proxy, etc), in some sort of http smuggling issue. For this agent, if you made a response, it means you had the whole message, and it can send the next message, where you will in fact think this is just another part of the body.

Now if you have the whole message, you can decide to send an early response and detach an asynchronous task to really perform some sort of stuff. but this means:

- you have to assume that **no more output should be generated**, you will not try to send any output to the request issuer, you should consider that the communication is now closed
- the worker thread should not receive new requests to manage, and this is the hard part. If this thread is marked as available for a new request, it may also be **killed** by the thread manager (you have in Nginx or Apache request counters associated with workers, and they are killed after reaching a limit, to create fresh ones). it may also receive a gracefull reload command (usually it's a kill), etc.

So you start to enter a zone where you should know the internals of the HTTP server, which is maybe managed by you, or not, and where changes may appear sooner or later. And you start to make very strange things, which leads usually to **strange issues**, hard to reproduce.

Uausally the best way to handle **asynchronous tasks**, while still being able to understand what happen, is to use a **messaging system**. Put a list of tasks in **queue**, and get a **parallel asynchronous worker process** which does things with theses tasks. track status of theses tasks if you need it.
Same things may apply with the client, after receiving a very fast HTTP answer, it may need to perform some ajax status polling for the task status. And you will maybe only have to check the status of the task in the queue to send a response.

You will get more control on the whole thing.

For me I really dislike having detached threads, coming from strange code, performing heavy tasks without any way of outputing a status or reporting errors, and maybe preventing the nice application stop calls (still waiting for strange threads to join) which does not imply a killall.

Comment: Thanks @regilero, this helped me lot and I have given you my bounty as well. Here is my understanding :
a) Thread gets request , 
b) doesn't care about status of an insert in a db ( say caching layer )
c) starts the insert call in async mode
d) sends the response hard coded OK to caller
-- This is not a good approach as web server managing threads might be waiting for these detached threads to complete before shutting down gracefully. Is this only the only problem ? Since here response doesn't care about status of async call. just hard coded OK is enough ( lets assume )

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether this asynchronous operation performs something which the client should be notified about.

If you return 200 OK (i.e. successfully completed) and later the asynchronous operation fails then the client will not know about the error.

You of course have some options like sending some kind of push notification over websocket or sending another request which would return the actual result and things like that. So basically depends on your needs...

Comment: Thanks but my question is : Will this thread still be available to take another request by the web-server. Or although the response is sent, but the thread is still waiting for the async call to come back and not taking any other request ( HTTP ). So lets say somebody asks me to build a REST API where s/he is not concerned about the POST request ultimately writes to db or not. Then I can either have a queue and just send the response back by putting it in a queue. The other is : have async call to DB and just return the response OK back ? Is it safe to do so ?

Comment: Yes, the thread will be available for other request as early as you return from your method. For the other part - I'd probably use Executor service for doing the asynchronous action instead of launching another thread. If you're using some third party library for this I assume they already get advantage of this.

Comment: Then suppose this thread now starts taking another request meanwhile the asynchronous call made earlier returns and throws exception. What will happen ? The new request will be surprised that what made it jump to the exception. isn't it ?
For clarity :
a) Thread T1 , takes a request 
b) makes ASYNC - db call 
c) immediately returns the response without waiting for the status of ASYNC call
d) T1 now takes a new HTTP request, 
e) While processing new request, previous ASYNC call throws Exception to T1.
What will happen ? T1 would get confused isn't it ?

Comment: The exception is thrown in thread which performs the operation, not the original one. Once it processes new request the other thread doesn't have any relation to it.

Comment: But it has to cascade to the parent thread which is now killed. What should be the behaviour by say JVM ? Parent thread is killed and child thread has to do stack unwinding...

Comment: @siddhusingh There is nothing like parent thread. If you don't catch the exception in the performing thread, the exception will be ignored or at most just logged to the JVM log (stderr usually).

Comment: Now the concern is : If we do this approach on heavy load. Web server's health would convey that it can take requests but there are threads still pending in the async call. This overall breaks the system. Isn't it ?